# Linked Server Column level Collation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, collation

I have a MSSQL 2012 linked server with the database collation set to Latin1_General_100_BIN2.

I am trying to query the linked server from a MSSQL 2005 database where the collation is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

When I execute the following query I receive: An invalid tabular data stream (TDS) collation was encountered.

```
SELECT
reel_key COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
FROM [SomeServer].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTable]
```

The linked server reel_key field is a char(7).

From what I've read and researched this should work but it does not. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: does it work if you wrap it in openquery and perform the collate on the remote side

Answer (score 0):

Try set property linked server 
Use Remote Collation = true
and set collation name

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'SERVER', 'use remote collation', 'true'
EXEC sp_serveroption 'SERVER', 'collation name', 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
```

or force sort

```
SELECT
reel_key 
FROM [SomeServer].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTable]
ORDER BY reel_key  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Neither one did the trick.  Here are my settings if that helps any...

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVER', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVER', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=N'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVER', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'